Derailleur Hanger - Fastener torque & thread preparation
Is there a recommended torque spec for derailleur hangar bolts in general, and is thread lock or grease recommended? If there's no generic torque spec for hangar bolts, what would be appropriate for these bolts?
2 bolts on the hangar which are:

Length 12mm
Diameter of outer thread 2.98mm
Pitch looks to be 20 threads per cm
Takes a 2.5mm hex key.

I noticed some play in the rear derailleur and the bolts had backed out a fair bit on their own during use. No thread lock was used for the initial assembly.

There isn’t a generic torque spec that encompasses all hanger bolts per se, but for the M3 x 0.5mm bolts you've identified, a good generic torque spec is 2-3 Nm. I would suggest using threadlocker on them.
Note that while of course you don't want loose parts on your bike, those bolts only hold the hanger on when the wheel is removed. It's not like you risk the derailleur falling off mid-ride. Under normal operation, the wheel fastening mechanism clamps the hanger to the frame dropout with way more force than those M3 bolts could ever dream of.

I accidentally stripped the derailleur hanger bolt on one of my bikes so that the hanger was only 'pinned' by the bolt, and it held on fine as long as the wheel was attached. It made maintenance more difficult of course, but other than that I had no issues. The clamping force of the skewer is orders of magnitude stronger than that of the bolt.

Given how much extra force the axle applies (even if QR) if you don't have threadlocker or you'd rather not use it on M3, it might be a good idea to tighten the screws a final time with the wheel done up properly. If anything compresses (perhaps a slight high spot in one of the parts or even the paint) when the axles is done up, that will mean the little screws are no longer tight and more prone to vibration. While the derailleur wouldn't fall off without those screws, it wouldn't take much bad luck for one to fall in a vulnerable part of the rear mech

@ChrisH Good idea. In practice it might be difficult since the bolts heads often end up under the QR nut or are otherwise inaccessible. Tightening the bolts a little more than you'd normally do them (with the QR disengaged) would have the same effect I believe?

@MaplePanda a similar effect on the thread, but more risk of damaging the head, so a good idea with care. The one I've had with QR was awkwardly accesible but already stripped (and that was M4 in a steel frame). Twin M3s are likely to be closer to the axle and more of an issue
